# Bash loop through multiple lines of netstat command output

Tags: bash, shell

I'm running this command (saved the output to a text file:

```
netstat -ntp | grep tcp | grep EST | grep 34341
```

which let's say it has the output bellow (can be one single line or multiple lines):

```
tcp      593      0 10.10.1.11:43856       10.10.2.14:3434      ESTABLISHED     146597/daemon-
tcp      417      0 10.10.1.11:43859       10.10.2.15:3434      ESTABLISHED     146567/daemon-
tcp      317      0 10.10.1.11:43121       10.10.2.16:3434      ESTABLISHED     146582/daemon-
```

Here's what I came up with so far (after reading your comments):

```
#! /bin/bash

SLEEP=5
COUNTER=0

recvq()
{
    while read -r proto recvq x local remote state x
    do
        if [[ "$proto" == tcp && "$state" == ESTABLISHED && "$remote" =~ .*:3434 ]]
        then
            printf "%d\n" "$recvq"
        fi
    done < "$1"
}

while true; do

        (( COUNTER++ ))
        # measure recvq value
        declare -A first
        while read -r socket recvq
        do
            first[$socket]=$recvq
        done < <(recvq netstat1.txt)

        # sleep
        sleep "$SLEEP"

        # measure recvq value after sleep
        declare -A second
        while read -r socket recvq
        do
            second[$socket]=$recvq
        done < <(recvq netstat2.txt)

        [ ${#first[*]} != ${#second[*]} ] && { echo "Arrays are different size"; }

        for ii in ${!first[*]}; do
            [ "${first[$ii]}" == "${second[$ii]}" ] || { echo different element $ii; exit 1; }
        done
        echo "Arrays are identical"

done
```

Now I need to compare the value of recvq (before sleep) with the value of recvq (after sleep) for each of the lines found in files. If any of the initial recvq value is the same with the final recvq value then do something.

The problem is that I always get arrays are identical even if they are not!

Comment: Do not write essays. Minify your question. Reduce it to the actual problem. [mcve]

Comment: *I already created the script that I need for a single line output but I can't figure it out for multiple lines* does this mean looping through the output is not enough? is it context sensitive? where is your actual problem (expected vs observed behavior)?

Comment: For a single line output it's working fine. I want to make it work for any output and by that I mean an output with one single line, or 2 lines or any number of lines

Comment: @BogdanStoica : First, I would drop the `grep 3434`, because you are going to check for this port later again. Then I would throw away the two header lines. This leaves you with data in tabular form, separated by white space. You can then use awk to pick the correct lines and collect the recv-Q values and write them to stdout - which you can then catch into a bash array, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that’s what I’m teying to do but with no success ;(

Comment: Apparently I'm in the point where I get the initial values of the RecvQ from all the output and I also do the same for the values after the sleep time. Save them into arrays and display them on screen. Can't figure out the compare part though

Answer (score 1):

I would do the parsing this way:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read proto recvq x x port state x
do
  if [[ "$proto" == tcp && "$state" == ESTABLISHED && "$port" =~ .*:3434$ ]]
  then
    printf "%d\n" "$recvq"
  fi
done < <(netstat -ntp)
```

You do not need `grep`, `cat` or `awk` for this.

Do not do copy-paste-programming. If you have code, you want to reuse, put it in a function.

Bash has associative arrays, you can use to store the received data per socket.

```
#! /bin/bash

recvq()
{
  while read proto recvq x local remote state x
  do
    if [[ "$proto" == tcp && "$state" == ESTABLISHED && "$remote" =~ .*:3434$ ]]
    then
      printf "%s/%s %d\n" "$local" "$remote" "$recvq"
    fi
  done < "$1"
}

# First measure

declare -A first
while read socket recvq
do
  first[$socket]=$recvq
done < <(recvq netstat1.txt)

# Wait

sleep 10

# Second measure

declare -A second
while read socket recvq
do
  second[$socket]=$recvq
done < <(recvq netstat2.txt)

# Compare measures

for socket in "${!first[@]}"
do
  if [[ "${first[$socket]}" == "${second[$socket]}" ]]
  then
    printf "match for %s: %d\n" "$socket" "${first[$socket]}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: You forgot to provide the input to your loop. Also, I think the OP wants to have the recvq values not printed, but accumulated into a bash array, perhaps to process them later on.

Comment: that's correct, I want to save the recvq value and compare to something else

Comment: Thanks cevig. Way easier and shorter code the way you mentioned...

Comment: It seems to be working but something is not good. The entries are not displayed in the right order and also the output is kinda weird: ```13:31:06 ▶  ./f.sh
match for 101: 0
match for 103: 0
match for 102: 0
match for 104: 0```. In the files I have 101,102,103,104 except for the last line in the 2nd file which is 105. So it should only display the matched entries I guess

Comment: so if I have 100 200 300 400 when I print it shows 100 300 200 400 instead of the order.. I really don't get it

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out in the end. Probably it would have worked just fine with associative arrays as @ceving suggested and also provided an answer but it was not working as expected.

I won't mark my own answer as the right one though. I've just posted it in case anyone might find it useful.

```
#/bin/bash

n1="$(cat netstat1.txt | awk '{split($5,a,":"); print a[1]"="$2}')"

sleep 5

n2="$(cat netstat2.txt | awk '{split($5,a,":"); print a[1]"="$2}')"

# check
for i in $n1; do
    ip1=`echo $i | awk '{split($i,a,"="); print a[1]}'`
    val1=`echo $i | awk '{split($i,a,"="); print a[2]}'`
    #echo $ip1 $val1

    for j in $n2; do

        ip2=`echo $j | awk '{split($j,a,"="); print a[1]}'`
        val2=`echo $j | awk '{split($j,a,"="); print a[2]}'`
        #echo $ip2 $val2

        if [ $ip1 == $ip2 ]; then
            if [ $val1 == $val2 ]; then
                echo "values: $val1 vs $val2 equal for remote ip: $ip1 => NOK! Do whatever!"
            else
                echo "values: $val1 vs $val2 dfferent for remote ip: $ip1 => OK"
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```